# Allocating memory on heap or passing work memory?

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management, coding-style

It happens relatively often that a function needs additional memory.

In old codes I often encountered that the additional space has to be provided by the caller and passed to the function as a work array. I guess that this leaves more flexibility to the calling function and might improve performance.

On the other hand allocating the memory guarantees that the memory is actually available and also simplifies the interface.

Is there something like a best practice for handling those cases?

Comment: How does the caller know how much space the callee needs to do it's job? Your first case just seems like bad software engineering. "You are a big enough chunk of code that you deserve your own function, but now I'm going to tie your implementation to the amount of memory I decide to give you". Voted to close a primarily opinion based.

Comment: Do You bring Your own seat into the car? The only sane reason of external mem-allocation coming to mind is for a function-output...

Comment: @John3136 I agree with you that it feels like bad software engineering, but if you have a function that is called frequently and needs an additional array of size n, where n is known at runtime, you can avoid allocating memory each time the function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C code it is common to let the caller take care of memory allocation, e.g. strcpy. The problem is that the called function doesn't know how much memory it can actually use. Therefore C has some functions where the caller also can specify a maximum, e.g. strncpy.

In C++ it is common to the let the called function handle memory allocation if needed. For instance vector::push_back. However, C++ still has functions where the caller is responsible, e.g. std::memcpy.

So there is no rule specifying one or the other. However, if possible it seems to be best pratice to let the called function handle memory allocation.

Still there are situations where the caller can get better performance by taking part in the allocation. Example: you call a function passing a (reference to a) vector and the called function will put data into the vector. If the caller knows that there will be added (push_backed) a lot of new elements and the caller knows the approximate number (e.g. 8000 to 10000), the caller can improve performance by reservering 10000 entries in the vector before doing the call. So this is like a joint effort. But the called function will still safely handle cases where more than 10000 entries are needed.

Answer (score 1):

"Old" codes that I've seen that require the caller to allocate memory for work arrays were written (or significant components of them were written) before dynamic memory allocation was a standard part of computing languages. (See Fortran 77, for example.)  They weren't doing it because they thought it was good practice so much as that computer science hadn't evolved far enough yet.  Unless you're linking to such a library for legacy reasons, dynamic allocation is the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if your function needs an array whose length you do not know and that does not have a small maximum size then the right way to go with this would be to use `new` or `malloc` and allocate memory on the heap.

Say for example you need to parse a file and read in its contents into an array and you have no idea how long the file is then using a `vector<>` would be the right way to go. And then when you make a call to `push_back()` the element you add goes somewhere on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

In *"heap or passing work memory"* you present a false dichotomy - *by far* the most common practice is for the called function to use the stack for its "working" memory.  Using the stack is faster than dynamic allocation, and ensures deallocation as execution leaves the variable's containing scope, even if due to an exception.

In cases where the called function is preparing a value to return to the caller... that's NOT simply "working" memory and I assume that's not what you're asking about, but FWIW in that situation the callee may wish to decouple the memory from the stack to allow the data's lifetime to outlive its own.  That's typically done using dynamic allocation, either implicitly when returning Standard Library containers, or explicitly with `new` (and hopefully shared pointers).